# MongoDB, positional argument, two levels deep - still not possible?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with the following structure:

```
event_id: "id",
votedUp: 0,
votedDown: 0,
questions: [
    {
        title: "title"
        desc: "desc"
        type: "TEXT"
        answers: []
    },
    {
        title: "title"
        desc: "desc"
        type: "MULTIPLE"
        answers: [
            {
                value: "ans1",
                answered: 0
            },
            {
                value: "ans2",
                answered: 2
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Important thing here: question doesn't make any sense without an Event, so it can't have it's own ID - they are identified by their properties within given Event.
This is some kind of questionnaire, mixed a little bit with survey.

**I have two use cases:**

User completes questionnaire.

- For TEXT questions, I need to push submitted answers.
- For multi/single choice I need to increment 'answered' field.

How can I achieve this WITHOUT changing the model using mongodb? I've found  [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831) issue and I'm quite terrified. It seems like there's no way to do this with one query.

Is it still the case? Any workarounds?

The only idea I have is to retrieve document from database, edit it and save again, but since mongo has nothing to do with transactions, it could be dangerous...

Comment: Probably best to justify your need for a feature with MongoDB themselves https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

Comment: If you knows `questions.type: "TEXT"` then you can push your  submitted answers in `answers` array, problem with if `type: "MULTIPLE"` then using mongo query is not possible to increment `answered` count as per jira issue you posted in your question , for this you used to iterate over array and then increment value

Comment: Yeah, thanks guys. I created separate collection for Quesions, I'm referencing them by eventId + props. The only problem is with adding order, so I used another hack - simple 'questionNumber' field... Anyway, I sill can't believe such a feature is not supported...